# issues with PDFMerger.php

Tags: php, merge

I want to merge 2 or more pdfs, but with the condition. I am using PDFMerger.php (http://pdfmerger.codeplex.com/). The code What I have found is :

```
<?php
   include 'PDFMerger.php';
   $pdf = new PDFMerger;
   $pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/one.pdf', '1, 3, 4')
       ->addPDF('samplepdfs/two.pdf', '1-2')
       ->addPDF('samplepdfs/three.pdf', 'all')
       ->merge('download', 'samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf');
?>
```

This code is working fine for me. But I have a problem here. I do not know the page count in my pdfs as they are generating dynamically. So what if I want to skip the first page or last page from the three.pdf(assume there are 5 pages) & I do not have the page count.

So the output should be all pages of one.pdf+all pages of two.pdf+2-5 pages of three.pdf

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use this following code to find number pages in PDF:

```
exec('/usr/bin/pdfinfo '.$tmpfname.' | awk \'/Pages/ {print $2}\'', $output);
```

or

```
function getNumPagesInPDF($file)
{
    if(!file_exists($file))return null;
    if (!$fp = @fopen($file,"r"))return null;
    $max=0;
    while(!feof($fp)) {
            $line = fgets($fp,255);
            if (preg_match('/\/Count [0-9]+/', $line, $matches)){
                    preg_match('/[0-9]+/',$matches[0], $matches2);
                    if ($max<$matches2[0]) $max=$matches2[0];
            }
    }
    fclose($fp);
    return (int)$max;

}
```

Comment: not getting anything. my files are in 'samplepdfs/one.pdf'. also tell me how to add this code to my program.

Comment: <?php
include 'PDFMerger.php';
$pdf = new PDFMerger;
$pagecount = getNumPagesPdf('samplepdfs/one.pdf');
for($i=0; $i<$pagecount; $i++)
{
 $pdf->AddPage();  // error is in this line
 $tplidx = $pdf->importPage($i+1, '/MediaBox');
 $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx, 10, 10, 200); 
}
$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/two.pdf', '1-2')
 ->addPDF('samplepdfs/three.pdf', 'all')
 ->merge('download', 'samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf');

Comment: thanks. now I got the page count. but what after that ? please see the code above & tell me